# How to add objects from different class into a doubly linked list

Tags: java, sockets, networking, doubly-linked-list

I am doing a project on networks and I'm stuck in adding objects to linked list. If I get any assistance I'll be grateful.

I have 7 different classes Source,Sink,Node_A,Node_B,Node_C,Node_D,Node_E which extends Node class.

I am trying to add the objects of above 7 classes by using `LinkedList` in util package,but in vain.

Also, I want to know whether we can give virtual address to Node, if yes then how?

Any assistance will help me to finish this project and I'll be very grateful, thank you in advance.

```
   Code Snippet:         

             Node class:
      import java.util.LinkedList;
     public class Node{
       static LinkedList<Node> List1=new LinkedList<Node> ();
       }

            Source class:
     public class Source extends Node{
        Node src=new Source();
        Node.List1.addFirst(src);
      }

            Node_A class:
     public class Node_A extends Node{
        Node na=new Node_A();
        Node.List1.add(na);
      }

           Node_B class:
     public class Node_B extends Node{
        Node nb=new Node_A();
        Node.List1.add(nb);
      }

            Sink class:
     public class Sink extends Node{
        Node snk=new Sink();
        Node.List1.addLast(snk);
      }
```

Comment: Might help to mention the language...

Comment: @John3136 Sorry forgot to mention i'm doing project using Java prgm language.

Comment: When you adding to LinkedList what error message do you get ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I do not get any error message but when i check size it just shows size as 1. I tried to add from single class like Source class, in that scenario i can add all objects but i want to add from different classes.

Comment: @PeterMmm Whenever, i try to add objects from the above code and check size of list, i get the value of list size as 1.

Comment: So show us the where you use the classes and retrieve the list's size.

Comment: @PeterMmm Thanks for the help, i've added all the objects from Node class, i have another question i'm having an object of Node type how to convert it into Socket object.                                      ` `

Comment: Socket, what `Socket` ? Maybe start a new question with your code ...

Comment: for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
                {
                    Socket tmp;
                tmp = (Socket)Node.List1.get(i);
                    int pno=tmp.getPort(); }

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to add code in comment section.

Comment: The code you've posted regarding adding items into a list will work. The problem is a bug somewhere else in your code.